# Selecting specific element

Tags: css

guys, I don't know how to select a specific selector of class/id if I have many Paragraphs and I just want to select a specific one how I'm supposed to do that. For example, if I want to select the second Paragraph how I'm supposed to that? `<p>World</p>` Can I somehow just select that or I need to add another class.

Example:

HTML:

```
<div class="class">
   <p>Hello</p>
   <p>World</p>
</div>
```

How can I select the second paragraph `<p>World</p>`

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at pseudo-class selector [:nth-of-type()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

In this case you just have to do `.class > div:nth-of-type(2)`

```css
.class > p:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="class">
   <p>Hello</p>
   <p>World</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be `.class > p:nth-child(2)`

Answer (score 2):

Id's are uniq for elements. If you define an id, you can use that.
HTML

```
<div class="class">
   <p id="hello">Hello</p>
   <p id="world">World</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#hello {
 css attributes..
}
#world {
 css attributes..
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:nth-child()` selector to select the nth element

This selects the second paragraph

```
.class p:nth-child(2){
  /* properties */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the [nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) or [last-child()](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp) to select the `<p>World</p>` element.

```css
.class p:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
}

.class1 p:last-child {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="class">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>World</p>
</div>

<div class="class1">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>World</p>
</div>
```